# When I download packages or files in Google Colab, does that consume my data?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Noob question here. Trying to set up Colab for work due to the situation right now.

If I download python packages or datasets in Google Colab using wget or pip, does that consume my data? To be clear, I only want to run code on Colab, and not download the models or files on my local system from colab.

Asking because my data limits are pretty low (1GB per day) and one large pre-trained model can finish it all up.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't consume (much) of your data.

Google Colab runs on Google Cloud. If it downloand some data, it travel to Google Cloud, not to your computer.

Only the text you type, the output text, and some images travel to your computer. Only the notebook contents. So, it consumes only a little for you.